# What is build number of the OS X Lion version released on the app store July 20th 2011?

Tags: macos, build-version

Can someone tell me what is build number of the Lion version released on the app store July 20th 2011?

Comment: Keep in mind: the new Macs ship with different build numbers (11A2051, or something like that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lion build is "Mac OS X Lion 10.7 (11A511)".

Comment: I believe that the build number of the app store released in OSX Lion is 1.1.1. The build number in Snow Leopard was 1.0.2 I believe. EDIT The build of Mac OSX Lion itself is 11A511. It turns out that the build number of the GM and the now are the same.

Comment: I have verified this.

Comment: Sorry, someone modified my post, I want to know what's the build number of lion itself

Comment: Where do you see that? My "About This Mac" just says "Version 10.7"

Comment: It's behind the "More Info" button on "About This Mac".